# Evaluating a surface integral on a sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to calculate a surface integral on a sphere and this integral came up.
$$\int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\dfrac{R}{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2-y^2}}{dy}{dx}$$
When I tried to compute the antiderivative, I got a negative hyperbolic complex function involving $x$ and $y$. Is there a possible way to get it in terms of natural log with no $i$?

Comment: How about using change of variables, perhaps to the radial co-ordinates?

Comment: Which is exactly the question? If the question is <How to get "it" in terms of $\ln$?> - where that "it" is an integral of the shape $$\int\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}\; dy$$where $a$ is the square root of $R^2-x^2\ge 0$ well then we cannot force a $\log$ instead of $\arcsin$ (except for also adding an $\exp$ to the formula). Please state one clear question, and show what you tried to answer it.

Comment: I actually got it in as -iarsinh(x/sqrt(y^2-R^2)). I was wondering if i could simplify it to natural log without having (i) in my function.

Answer (score 1):

The given double integration is on the disk of radius $R$. So let us change to the polar coordinates. Then the integral becomes $$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R\frac{Rr}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}drd\theta=2\pi R\int_0^R\frac{r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}dr$$

Which is pretty easy to calculate (Hint: Substitute $R^2-r^2=v^2$).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't thought of using polar coordinates. I thought cartesian would work here.

Comment: @Alv When you see radial symmetry in the integrand it is a good idea to use polar coordinates. When you see terms of the form $x^{2}+y^{2}$ or $r^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}$ , it reeks of a polar substitution and it's not a bad strategy to change to polar coordinates and see if it simplifies the integral

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks, i thought if i get the limits rights i would be able to get answer but integral became complicated.